# Uncaught TypeError: a.customFilter is not a function with ngAnimate

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I'm working on an AngularJS application, and I tried to add Angular Animate.

Angular Route didn't cause any problem, but it seems Angular Animate is not compatible with something in my app.

I load the libs in this order:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular/angular.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular-animate/angular-animate.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../node_modules/angular-route/angular-route.min.js"></script>
```

And use them in my `app.js`:

```
var app = angular.module('tictactoe', ['ngRoute', 'ngAnimate']);
```

I'm getting the following error. JQuery and Angular (Vanilla + Route + Animate) have been installed with *npm*

[image: My error]

Dependencies versions:

[image: versions]

Comment: What versions are the packages?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Use angular version `1.6.5` or downgrade angular-animate version to `1.6.4` It'll solve the issue.
Here's a plunk of some angular app example in which this dependency condition can be verified (just change versions of libraries in cdn link)

https://plnkr.co/edit/v0cLmZvYAC8m1J7JdwHf?p=preview

Comment: Yeah, it seems to be an Angular compatibility version issue, thanks !

Comment: @Zooly Welcome :)

Comment: This helped. I used `<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/angular.js/1.6.4/angular-animate.min.js"></script>` from the plunker code attached :)

Answer (score 0):

Please downgrade to version angular animate 1.6.4.
Here are the file you should also download it from that link. it works for me.

```
https://code.angularjs.org/1.6.4/
```

Also change bower.json (angular-animate/bower.json)
[image]

Comment: Hi Umar! This question has already solved by Shantanu. Thanks anyway for your help.

Comment: No problem. i just put a solution. because it works for me.